# Добавить в pandas столбец с промежуточными суммами по групам

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Есть данные по продажам. нужно добавить для каждого счета общее количество штук различных товаров по счету.  Другими совами - добавить столбец где для каждой группы будет сумма столбца по данной группе. Данный код работает.

```
import pandas as pd


df_fee = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        sku=2*[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
        order_id=3*[3, 3, 4, 5],
        quantity=4*[ 1, 2, 3],
    )
)


def __count_nd_fill_units_by_group(g):
    order_sum = g['quantity'].sum()
    g.loc[:, "units_in_order"] = order_sum
    #   
    # g = g.assign(units_in_order=order_sum)
    #             
    return g

print(df_fee)   
df_fee.loc[:, "units_in_order"] = None
df_fee = df_fee.groupby(['order_id', ], group_keys=False).apply(__count_nd_fill_units_by_group)
df_fee.sort_values(by=['order_id',], inplace=True)
print(df_fee)
```

и выдает такой результат:

```
        sku  order_id  quantity
0     1         3         1
1     1         3         2
2     2         4         3
3     3         5         1
4     4         3         2
5     4         3         3
6     1         4         1
7     1         5         2
8     2         3         3
9     3         3         1
10    4         4         2
11    4         5         3
    sku  order_id  quantity  units_in_order
0     1         3         1              12
1     1         3         2              12
4     4         3         2              12
5     4         3         3              12
8     2         3         3              12
9     3         3         1              12
2     2         4         3               6
6     1         4         1               6
10    4         4         2               6
3     3         5         1               6
7     1         5         2               6
11    4         5         3               6
```

> d:\onedrive\projects\chud_amaz\soft_in_dev\moduled_way_oop\code_questions\order_total_units_filling.py:21: FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
> g.loc[:, "units_in_order"] = order_sum

Два вопроса.

1. по ощущениям можно лучше (короче, проще, быстрее)
2. что за сообщение выдается в конце. Это потенциально опасно?

Comment: сообщение предупреждает, что в будущем pandas _всегда_ будет менять значения сразу в исходном фрейме, а не создавать новый список. Собственно, сейчас он так же поступает и предлагает, если хотите, чтобы присваивание работало по-старому, воспользуйтесь указанными рекомендациями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно короче, конечно:

```
import pandas as pd

df_fee = pd.DataFrame(dict(sku=2*[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], order_id=3*[3, 3, 4, 5], quantity=4*[ 1, 2, 3],))

df_fee["units_in_order"] = df_fee.groupby("order_id")["quantity"].transform(sum)
df_fee.sort_values("order_id",  inplace=True)
```

df_fee:

```
    sku  order_id  quantity  units_in_order
0     1         3         1              12
1     1         3         2              12
4     4         3         2              12
5     4         3         3              12
8     2         3         3              12
9     3         3         1              12
2     2         4         3               6
6     1         4         1               6
10    4         4         2               6
3     3         5         1               6
7     1         5         2               6
11    4         5         3               6
```